# Create an AAR and XCFramework from a .Net MAUI class library

Tags: mono, maui, aar, xcframework, embeddinator

I am creating a .Net MAUI class library that will have some business logic.
[image]

---

I want to use this class library in native Android and iOS apps written with Kotlin, Java and Swift.
I am not sure if .Net supports this or is there any tool available like [Embeddinator-4000](https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000) which could produce AAR/Jar for Android and Framework/XCFramework for iOS.

[KMM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-getting-started.html) would have been a great tool if I only wanted to support the mobile platforms, but I want to use this shared library in a Windows app too.

Comment: For more information about the supported platforms of Net MAUI class library, you may refer to the link:"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72067147/net-maui-how-to-create-a-class-library".